# Bash: read property file into Array

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to read a property file like this one into a set of arrays:

```
DATABASE="mysql57"
DB_DRIVER_XA="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource"
DB_DRIVER_CLASS="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

DATABASE="db2_111"
DB_DRIVER_XA="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource"
DB_DRIVER_CLASS="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
```

I've found the following grep to be useful to store each key into its array:

```
filename=conf.properties
dblist=($(grep "DATABASE" $filename)) 
xadriver=($(grep "DB_DRIVER_XA" $filename)) 
driver=($(grep "DB_DRIVER_CLASS" $filename))
```

The problem is that the above solution stores into the array KEY=VALUE:

```
printf '%s\n' "${dblist[@]}"
DATABASE="mysql57"
DATABASE="db2_111"
```

I'd like to have in each array only the value. Is there a simple way to do it rather than looping over the array and maybe use "cut" to remove the "KEY=" part?

Comment: Wondering...do you have control over the property file ? I mean, can it be modified to something like : DATABASE[1]="mysql57", DB_DRIVER_XA[1]="com.mysql ........ and so on. Then you would only have to source the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk -F=` to split each line into key and value, and `sed` to strip out the quotes.

```
dblist=(  $(awk -F= '$1=="DATABASE"        {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g'))
xadriver=($(awk -F= '$1=="DB_DRIVER_XA"    {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g'))
driver=(  $(awk -F= '$1=="DB_DRIVER_CLASS" {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g'))
```

Then, it would be better to use `readarray` to populate arrays to prevent word splitting on spaces and glob expansion on `*` and `?`.

```
readarray -t dblist   < <(awk -F= '$1=="DATABASE"        {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g') 
readarray -t xadriver < <(awk -F= '$1=="DB_DRIVER_XA"    {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g') 
readarray -t driver   < <(awk -F= '$1=="DB_DRIVER_CLASS" {print $2}' "$filename" | sed 's/"//g')
```

Comment: I like to show incremental improvements in my answers so the final result isn't out of the blue. The first step is replacing `grep` with `awk | sed`. The second is switching from assignment to `readarray`.

Comment: Don't need sed here: `awk -F= '$1=="DB_DRIVER_CLASS" {gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' "$filename"`

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
databases=()
xas=()
classes=()
while IFS="=" read -r var value; do
    without_quotes=${value//\"/}
    case $var in
        DATABASE) databases+=( "$without_quotes" ) ;;
        DB_DRIVER_XA) xas+=( "$without_quotes" ) ;;
        DB_DRIVER_CLASS) classes+=( "$without_quotes" ) ;;
    esac
done < file

declare -p databases xas classes
```

```
declare -a databases='([0]="mysql57" [1]="db2_111")'
declare -a xas='([0]="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource" [1]="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource")'
declare -a classes='([0]="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" [1]="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")'
```

The take-away is to use `IFS` with the `read` command to split the line into fields, and store the results in separate variables.

Comment: This is more efficient than my answer because it reads `file` in one go rather than three separate passes.